# Help clarify Pilot's difficulty balancing forces acting on aircraft during cruise stage?

Tags: flight-controls, flight-training, g-forces

How does the ideal disposition of the four forces in an aircraft relate to the nose-up or nose-down pitching moments? What are the difficulties that the pilot can face to maintain such an ideal disposition for each of the forces while cruising? And also, Do these forces values and positions depend on the airspeed and the angle of attack?

THANKS.

Comment: It's not real clear what you are asking, but it isn't hard at all.  Once you are all trimmed up in cruise most airplanes are pretty stable in smooth air and fly themselves.

Comment: The hard work has already been done by the aircraft designers, making the pilot's job easier.

Comment: I suggest you read the section about forces of [how it flies](http://www.av8n.com/how/htm/4forces.html). "the 4 forces" is mainly a artificial decomposition of thrust (due to engine), weight and aerodynamic forces (which are sums and then artificially split in its horizontal and vertical component)

Comment: … and also the *preceding* chapters about energy management and angle of attack. Or the [whole thing](http://www.av8n.com/how/), it's quite good read.